# Django + Postfix e-mail de password reset não é enviado

Tags: django, gmail, postfix

Eu configurei um servidor com meu aplicativo *Django* e agora estou tentando habilitar o reset de senha via e-mail usando o *postfix* como servidor de e-mail.

Eu comecei configurando minhas views e testando se tudo estava correto através do *console e-mail backend* do *Django*.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Quando eu entro no meu site e peço para resetar a senha eu vejo o e-mail corretamente aparecendo no meu terminal.

Em seguida eu configurei o *postfix* no meu servidor. Também testei para ver se ele estava funcionando corretamento através do seguinte comando:

```
echo "Body" | mail -s "Subject" myemail@gmail.com
```

Tudo certo até aqui, o e-mail acima chegou no meu e-mail de teste.

Após isso modifiquei o `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Noreply <noreply@mydomain.com>'
```

Quando eu testo a configuração no *django shell*:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Subject', 'Body', 'noreply@mydomain.com', ['myemail@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Novamente tudo ocorre como o esperado e o e-mail chega na minha caixa.

Porém o que não funciona é quando eu acesso a página de reset de senha do meu site e entro com meu e-mail o e-mail não chega!

No meu `journalctl -u postfix -xe` eu vejo as seguintes mensagens:

```
postfix/smtpd[23411]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
postfix/smtpd[23411]: 7BAED13D02E: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
postfix/cleanup[23414]: 7BAED13D02E: message-id=<20170820234125.23051.46440@mydomain.com>
postfix/qmgr[20567]: 7BAED13D02E: from=<noreply@mydomain.com>, size=974, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/smtpd[23411]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
postfix/smtp[23415]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx::xx]:25: Network is unreachable
postfix/smtp[23415]: 7BAED13D02E: to=<myemail@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25, delay=0.32, delays=0.01/0.01/0.1/0.21, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx] said: 550-5.7.1 [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx      13] Messages with multiple addresses in From: 550 5.7.1 header are not accepted. f12si6029290pln.103 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
postfix/cleanup[23414]: CB6B913D030: message-id=<20170820234125.CB6B913D030@mydomain.com>
postfix/qmgr[20567]: CB6B913D030: from=<>, size=3367, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/bounce[23416]: 7BAED13D02E: sender non-delivery notification: CB6B913D030
postfix/qmgr[20567]: 7BAED13D02E: removed
postfix/local[23418]: CB6B913D030: to=<noreply@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0/0.01/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "noreply")
postfix/qmgr[20567]: CB6B913D030: removed
```

Acredito que e dica esteja em `13] Messages with multiple addresses in From: 550 5.7.1 header are not accepted. f12si6029290pln.103 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)`, mas não sei como resolver...

Comment: Você poderia postar o código da view onde você envia o email ou então se está utilizando a view do django authentication system ? Você está seguindo os passos daqui:
 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/) ?

Comment: Estou usando a view *default* do django https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py

Comment: Eu tive alguns problemas com email, devido ao SSL.. Eu usava o Zoho. Tive que usar o django_smtp_ssl no EMAIL_BACKEND e colocar a flag pra EMAIL_USE_SSL para True. No caso, sua porta está correta? É a 25 mesmo? Não sei se interfere, mas no DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, eu coloco apenas o email e não Espacos e caracteres. Mas também não sei se isso interfere em algo. Uma dica também, é usar filas para enviar o email. Coloca em uma fila e faz o send manualmente, como voce fez, jogando uma quantidade X por vez da fila.